# What does this regular expression mean: (?![#$])

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex

Can someone give me an example/explanation what this regular expression does:

`(?![#$])`

This is part of `<%(?![#$])(([^%]*)%)*?>` which is what ASP.NET uses to parse server-side code blocks. I understand the second part of the expression but not the first.

I checked the documentation and found `(?! ...)` means a zero-width negative lookahead but I'm not entirely sure I understand what that means. Any input I tried so far that looks like `<% ... %>` seems to work - I wonder why this first sub-expression is even there.

**Edit:**
I came up with this expression for picking up ASP.NET expressions: `<%.+?%>` then I found the one Microsoft made (the above full expression in question). I'm trying to understand why they chose that particular expression when mine seems a lot simpler. (I'm trying to see if my expression ignores certain boundary conditions that the MS one doesn't.)

Comment: Regex: `<%(?![#$])(([^%]*)%)*?>` - the new APL: `⎕←{⍵⍨~{⍵∨≠\⍵}⍵∊'<>'}txt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that matches if the next character is not `#` or `$`, but doesn't consume it.

It's very simlar to the negative character class `[^#$]` except that the negative character class also consumes the character, preventing it from being matched by the rest of the expression.

To see the difference consider matching `<%test%>`.

- The expression `<%(?![#$])(([^%]*)%)*?>` captures `test%`. [(rubular)](http://www.rubular.com/r/JjDiEJpS4n)
- The expression `<%[^#$](([^%]*)%)*?>` captures `est%` because the `t` was consumed by the negative character class. [(rubular)](http://www.rubular.com/r/ZXnqeAvf6I)

Comment: Mark, thanks for the answer. Is there an example that wouldn't match this regex? I'm asking because I'm trying to understand why this would be better than just using `<%.+?%>` instead. All examples I tried so far seem to match both the same way.

Comment: @xxbbcc: `<%#thisshouldntmatch%>`